# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component ID has already been found in the view

Tags: java, jsf, composite-component

I am getting the "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Component ID  has already been found in the view" exception under certain circumstances and I do not understand why.

I have the following page where I am using a composite component four times, and there is a corresponding output text used to display the result of each:

```
<h:form id="aCrazyTestForm"">

   <my:jqueryautocomplete values="#{jqueryAutoCompleteBean.carListJson}" selectedValue="#{jqueryAutoCompleteBean.selectedCarOne}" field="make">
                <f:ajax execute=":aCrazyTestForm:completeOne" render=":aCrazyTestForm:completeOne" event="tagSelectedEvent" listener="#{jqueryAutoCompleteBean.selectedCarOne}" />
            </my:jqueryautocomplete>

            <h:outputText id="completeOne" value="#{jqueryAutoCompleteBean.selectedCarOne}" />

            <my:jqueryautocomplete values="#{jqueryAutoCompleteBean.carListJson}" selectedValue="#{jqueryAutoCompleteBean.selectedCarTwo}" field="make">
                <f:ajax execute=":aCrazyTestForm:completeTwo" render=":aCrazyTestForm:completeTwo" event="tagSelectedEvent" listener="#{jqueryAutoCompleteBean.selectedCarTwo}" />
            </my:jqueryautocomplete>

            <h:outputText id="completeTwo" value="#{jqueryAutoCompleteBean.selectedCarTwo}" />

            <my:jqueryautocomplete values="#{jqueryAutoCompleteBean.carListJson}" selectedValue="#{jqueryAutoCompleteBean.selectedCarThree}" field="make">
                <f:ajax  execute=":aCrazyTestForm:completeThree" render=":aCrazyTestForm:completeThree" event="tagSelectedEvent" listener="#{jqueryAutoCompleteBean.selectedCarThree}" />
            </my:jqueryautocomplete>

            <h:outputText id="completeThree" value="#{jqueryAutoCompleteBean.selectedCarThree}" />

            <my:jqueryautocomplete values="#{jqueryAutoCompleteBean.carListJson}" selectedValue="#{jqueryAutoCompleteBean.selectedCarFour}" field="make">
                <f:ajax  execute=":aCrazyTestForm:completeFour" render=":aCrazyTestForm:completeFour" event="tagSelectedEvent" listener="#{jqueryAutoCompleteBean.selectedCarFour}" />
            </my:jqueryautocomplete>

            <h:outputText id="completeFour" value="#{jqueryAutoCompleteBean.selectedCarFour}" />

</h:form>
```

My composite component implementation is wrapped in a span with id = "#{cc.clientId}"

I only encounter this error if I populate the form's id.If I set the form prependId="false", then I do not get the error.

With the below code I get the error:
"Unhandled Faces error: Component ID aCrazyTestForm:j_idt15 has already been found in the view". In the following snippet you can see that this is actually the id of my custom component.

```
<JqueryAutoComplete id="j_idt15" immediate="false" inView="true" localValueSet="false" rendered="true" required="false" transient="false" valid="true">
```

I thought that wrapping the composite component's implementation in a span with id="#{cc.clientId}" ensures that my component gets a unique identifier wherever it is used?

Comment: look at the generated page source. which and what ids collapse?

Comment: I can't see the generated source page when the error occurs...you see the HTML of the error page

Comment: Why do you set a generated ID in the first place? Either use a custom one or let JSF generate it.

Comment: This is just a guess, but I think there is a server-side DOM in JSF, which includes your composite components, and there is the client-sided DOM in form of (X)HTML. The clientID you are trying to set on a span inside the CC is probably the same as its parent's. You can easily check that out by setting `id=#{cc.clientId}_foo` and then looking into the generated HTML.

Answer (score 1):

JSF can become confused at times with repeating elements, especially with a number of elements that repeat.  Could you try setting IDs for each **my:jqueryautocomplete** tag and see if the problem persists?

Comment: Hi! I have similar issue but give me a tip pls. Should I really set id for each page component in case of using viewscoped or it is fine to have the id-s to be generated automatically?